# Ever use a photoshop brush in a commercial design? How do you attribute credit back?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-commons

I'm looking at increasing my photoshop brush collection and I keep coming across this license: [Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/) for example on this page: http://qbrushes.net/grunge/hi-res-mess/

The license asks for attribution back, well if I'm using it in a design for a commercial client's website, how does one do that?

The license also says it cannot be used for commercial work, but the description says "License: you may use them as you wish for commercial and none commercial use. Enjoy."

Now I'm confused...

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  Voting to move to Super User.

Comment: how do i move to Super User?

Comment: You can't directly, except by asking another question.  Five people with enough reputation to cast close votes can vote "off topic here, but move to Super User" (that's one of the listed possibilities).

Comment: Ask the author if you're that concerned. Clearly there's a mixed message that can't be answered here, and a very good question as to where a website (with no credits) would mention such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're at all unsure, speak to a lawyer.**

Yes the text & link point to completely different CC licenses which contradict each other around the Commercial uses open to you. **Seek clarification from the copyright owner.**

---

That said... check out [the full text of the license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/legalcode).

Its section **4. Restrictions** that you want. Look at part 'd' in particular as that contains specific information on attribution.

**Do not** ignore any part of the license though. Its all important.